# Sublime text nice indents

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a plugin or built in function that changes

```
'test' => $test,
'test123' => $test123,
'something_else' => $something_else
```

to

```
'test'           => $test,
'test123'        => $test123,
'something_else' => $something_else
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several [alignment plugins](https://packagecontrol.io/search/align) available on Package Control, my personal favourite is [AlignTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab).

Comment: Installed it, and loving it. Thanks! :D

Answer (score -1):

You can select code that you need format

**Edit-> Line -> Reintend**

But This is not more accurate

Comment: It does something different, thanks for the tip though! :)